# Issue in getting user location through geocode

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

Hello I am using following code to get user location, But i am facing one problem. Either I allow or block sharing my location it's going in error part.

Following is my code:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
var location_timeout = setTimeout("geolocFail()", 10000);

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    clearTimeout(location_timeout);

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

    geocodeLatLng(lat, lng);
}, function(error) {
    clearTimeout(location_timeout);
    geolocFail();
});
} else {
// Fallback for no geolocation
geolocFail();
}
```

Comment: What browser? Any error messages in the JavaScript console? Is the page requested over HTTPS:?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must request over HTTPS to get location, as geolocation can be fetched over on secure urls.